# Simple curve fitting smoothing algorithm

Tags: algorithms, regression, curves

Is there any conditionally simple algorithm to obtain a best fit (equation) for points set? I have a few points for which I want to have a "smooth" function is constructed that approximately fits the data. I've read about Gauss–Newton algorithm, but problem is that I don't implement it by itself. My task is create a UI graph and for general view (when I need to show all data in small screen area) I want to substitute a noisy curve with smooth curve (like [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys06e.gif)).

Comment: Have you tried [smoothing splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline)? There are many existing implementations, e.g. in [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html).

Comment: @Budenn, thanx! My problem is to split the data set to segments to apply the smoothing splines per each one.